# Domain Name Servers set by two different hosts

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

Can I add multiple hosts name servers for the same domain?

Let's say I have a domain on Godaddy, can I set WordPress Name Servers AND AWS Name Servers on it?

**Specific Scenario:**

1. I have static pages on Wordpress
2. I have django application behind an ELB on AWS
3. I want both to be on **new.example**
4. I want the static pages served by `new.example`
5. I want `app.new.example` to serve the django application.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I add multiple hosts name servers for the same domain?

Technically, yes (all domain names have typically at least two nameservers), but in the context of your question, no, as it would not operate the way you think it does.

You delegate your domain name to a set of nameservers that have **all** the content of the zone. It does not matter where the content pointed by records in the zone are handled, it can be elsewhere.

You will have to choose one company to provide DNS service to you, and then through their web panel or equivalent you will point `new.example` to point to your static pages on WordPress, and `app.new.example` to point to ELB on AWS.

Comment: Thank you @patrick-mevzek. So if I can put the WordPress nameservers only. Then configure in WordPress to point app.new.example to my ELB? I tried that but then wordpress only takes an IP for the A record. I can't use the ELB alias.

Comment: "only takes an IP for the A record." Which is 100% correct, a DNS `A` record is to map a name to an IPv4 address, there is no other data possible to use there.